# Is there a single function for matching and replacing?

Tags: python, regex

I wonder if there is a simpler alternative (e.g. a single function call) for matching and replacing to the following example:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> line = 'file:///windows-d/academic%20discipline/study%20objects/areas/formal%20systems/math'
>>> 
>>> match = re.match(r'^file://(.*)$', line)
>>> if match and match.group(1):
...     substitution = re.sub(r'%20', r' ', match.group(1))
... 
>>> substitution
'/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/math'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: exactly shown in the output.

Comment: you mean this `/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/math`?

Comment: yes.      @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to dodge your regex question and suggest you use something else for this:

```
>>> line = 'file:///windows-d/academic%20discipline/study%20objects/areas/formal%20systems/math' 
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote(line)
'file:///windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/math'
```

Then just strip off the `file://` with a slice or `str.replace` if necessary.

`%20` (space) is not the only escaped character possible here, so it's better to use the right tool for the job than have your regex solution break later when there is another character needing un-escaping.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below simple python code,

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'file:///windows-d/academic%20discipline/study%20objects/areas/formal%20systems/math'
>>> m = re.sub(r'%20|file://', r' ', line).strip()
>>> m
'/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/math'
```

`re.sub(r'%20|file://', r' ', line).strip()` code replaces the string `%20` or `file://` with a space. And again the `strip()` function removes all the leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'file:///windows-d/academic%20discipline/study%20objects/areas/formal%20systems/math'
>>> re.sub(r'^file://(.*)$', lambda m: m.group(1).replace('%20', ' '), s)
'/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/math'
```

---

```
>>> s = 'file:///windows-d/academic%20discipline/study%20objects/areas/formal%20systems/math'
>>> s.replace('file://', '').replace('%20', ' ')
'/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/math'
```

Comment: A simple `s.replace('%20', ' ')` would do the same (but @wim's answer is obviously better in this particular case).